# Should I get a larger cage for my two dwarf hamsters? How large?

Tags: hamsters, cage

I have two Russian female dwarf hamsters and they share a  25 x 30 x 50cm wired cage from pets at home which was highly recommended for two dwarfs. It seemed cramped with all the chews and toys, so I removed most of the toys which made it a bigger spacing things out.

Rosey, one of my dwarfs, started to bar climb and chew on the cage, because she loves to have lots of toys in the cage. I need to get a larger cage for the two. I want something large and cheap.

The zoo-zone 2 was recommended. Is it a good size or should I look for something else?

Comment: Hello! I edited your question to remove the shopping aspect and to attract more attention. If I accidentally changed the meaning of your question, please use the edit button to correct it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want something large and cheap: build yourself.

My advice for easy, cheap AND easy to clean:

- Take waterproof wooden plates, and build a box with 3 sides.
- In the 4th side, attach wooden sticks, to create a groove to slide in a pane of acrylic glass or something similar. Then, you can see the hamster easily, and you can slide it out to clean the cage!
- Build a lid with a hamster-proof grating, and you are set.

This way, you can build it just the right shape for the room, and easily add a second level as well (4 sticks, a plate on top, and a way for the hamster to climb up. Put that in the box, and you have a second level).

Also, you should possibly be aware that "recommended" in pet-store-lists usually is the absolute minimum. I saw recommendations for 1m² per hamster.

Please note that minimum base size is half of that, so 5 levels of 0,2m² would not count... but 2 levels of 0,5m² would.

Comment: Yeah, I typically prefer to build a cage myself... easy and inexpensive with some youtube videos. Should take no longer than an hour to build the cage once you get the proper tools... I just use a sander, hammer, drill, and a marble saw. A few diamond cutters. Yep! That do the job!